# ERROR Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, expo, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm facing a probleme went starting my react native expo App.
I experienced this issue afther updating my dependencies, in the propose of building my app.